# Regular Expression Transformation Interpretation

Tags: regex, text, expression, sublimetext2, transformation

I am working in `Sublime Text 2` to define symbols for the `goto:@ command`. I need help interpreting this regular expression transformation:

```
<key>symbolTransformation</key>
<string>s/\/\*\*\s*(.*?)\s*\*\//** $1 **/; s/\/\*.*?\*\*\//./; s/\/\*[^\*].*?[^\*]\*\///</string>
```

My intent is to edit the transformation, but I need to understand it first.

Is there a reference to learning this particular syntax? I'm relatively new to regular expressions and all the \ and / make me crazy! :)

Failing that, can someone walk me through the pieces of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we "unwrap" the regular expressions, they are respectively:

- replace `/\*\*\s*(.*?)\s*\*/` with `** $1 **`;
- replace `/\*.*?\*\*/` with `.`;
- replace `/\*[^*].*?[^*]\*/` with nothing (the empty string).

First regex:

```
/\*\*   # Look for '/' followed by two occurrences of '*',
\s*     # followed by zero or more space characters,
(.*?)   # followed by zero or more of any character, lazily (with capture),
\s*     # followed by zero or more space characters,
\*/     # followed by a '*' and a '/'
```

As the quantifier in the capture is lazy (`*?`), it means the regex engine will try and match the minimum possible amount of text before the next component of the regex (`\s*`) is satisfied (unlike a normal, "greedy" quantifier like `*` which will try and match the maximum possible amount before giving text back to satisfy the next component, if needed). The capture is available as `$1` in the replacement text.

Second regex:

```
/\*      # Look for a '/' then a '*',
.*?      # followed by zero or more of any character, lazily,
\*\*/    # followed by two '*' and a '/'
```

And replace all of this with a single dot (`.`).

Third regex:

```
/\*      # Look for a '/' then a '*',
[^*]     # followed by one character which is not a '*',
.*?      # followed by zero or more of any character, lazily,
[^*]     # followed by one character which is not a '*',
\*/      # followed by a '*' then a '/'.
```

And replace all of this with the empty string.